# Multiple outputs to multiple sound cards

Tags: sound

Yes, I KNOW this question has been asked many times and many a solution given. I know that in v20.04 the possibilities have improved. I've read tons of articles and questions on UBUNTU's and other distros' sites. HOWEVER...

I am not someone with a laptop and a guitar. I write for the symphony orchestra exclusively using sample libraries. Now, I don't know of any ample good quality orchestral library for Linux, so here's the problem: Some of the instruments in these libraries sound pretty good, but some of them not so good, even off of the best libraries. For example, groups of violins and violas at higher registers are harsh and brittle, (oh, that digital sound!). Of course, I doctor them up (EQ, etc.) and they sound well on their individual track, but when mixed they're back to the original, brittle and harsh sound. This is why I must recur to something else. If you think that I am the only one who has this problem, that is bad mixing techniques, just listen to demo tracks issued at sample library manufacturers' sites. In order to mask the problem, the tracks are full of loud brass and percussion, and/or violins playing at low registers, so they'd come out less harsh.

Here are my thoughts. Orchestras are recorded with many microphones, placed in strategic capture points for each section. The number of tracks can reach 60 to 80 or more. All of these tracks then get mixed down to the final 2 Stereo, or sometimes 5.1 for SADCDs (Super Audio Compact Disc). Unless one has an audio system worth $50,000 no CD would ever do justice to the orchestra. This is why I'd like to export my audio files to Ubuntu/Ardour and then play them through 16 separate speakers where the violin and viola sections would have their separate output channel to a separate speaker. All of the other instruments would be mixed group-wise down to 15 tracks, coming out to 15 speakers, but not 2 stereo tracks, permitting me to listen to what I wrote in optimal conditions. Since I don't write commercially (don't sell any of my writings), mixing it down further to 2 tracks isn't an issue, and it's not even desirable. Importing the audio tracks into Ardour would not lead to drift, since giving the same tempo to all of the tracks (recorded at the same tempo in the Windows DAW) would be enough. In my case, having 2 like cards they could easily be clocked if necessary if Ardour had that possibility by routing multiple independent busses to the cards. I might be wrong about Ardour as far as routing, so I apologize in advance.

Not having the money for the Cadillac solution (RME's $2000+ cards), I thought that, finally, Ardour would cater to people (many) who write for the orchestra and not only to those with a laptop and a guitar. I think I was wrong, although Ubuntu would have that possibility via jack, alsa, etc.

This writing is NOT to put down people who write for the guitar, since I myself do it quite a lot, but with orchestral accompaniment (well, most of the time anyway).

Thank you for reading, sincerely yours,

John.

PS: I apologize for this long writing with things that may be unclear to some of you.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is why is PAPREFS not included in Studio, since it's an old program, so useful  to serve the needs of many people running computers with multiple sound cards. Thank you for your inquiry, John.

Comment: That's not really a question we can answer here. We don't answer questions on behalf of developers but we can help you if you encounter an issue.  Sometimes devs make a decision that some software isn't needed by enough people to warrant it being installed by default. (There are just as many people who don't want "bloat")  It seems that the package `paprefs` is available in the `universe` repository, so you can install it easily with `apt` or your GUI package manager.

Comment: I understand that, but Paprefs is such an infinitesimally small program and so incredibly useful, that it'd hardly qualify as bloat. Sorry to disagree. Yours, John.

Comment: Hi and welcome and thanks for giving a glimpse into how you're using Ubuntu! As Nmath mentioned you can easily install the `paprefs` package. If you would like to suggest to developers that it should be included by default in Ubuntu Studio, I think [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/) is the place to do that (Launchpad is the platform for developing Ubuntu - this site is just a volunteer community producing a library of Q&A to help people use Ubuntu - we have no power in such matters). If there's something we here *can* do to help with your work, please update your question, thanks!